# NetLogo R Extension Installation Error in Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: java, r, macos, netlogo, osx-yosemite

I am having problems installing the R extension for NetLogo. I'm using NetLogo 5.05 and version 1.3 of the extension, which is supposed to work with R version 3.0 or higher. My version of R is 3.1.2.

Following the instructions from this [page](http://blogs.neuwirth.priv.at/software/2012/09/08/netlogo-the-r-extension-and-mountain-lion/), I have changed the .plist file within the NetLogo app so that it points to jri and to my R installation:

```
<key>NSJavaRoot</key>
    <string>..</string>
<key>LSEnvironment</key>
    <dict>
<key>JRI_HOME</key>
    <string>/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/rJava/jri</string>
<key>R_HOME</key>
    <string>/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources</string>
</dict> 
</dict>
</plist>
```

Adding `extensions [r]` to my code tab causes the error:

> Error in R-Extension: Error in runOnce: java.lang.NullPointerException

The developer [page](http://r-ext.sourceforge.net) says that the version for NetLogo 5 is still a beta, but I get the same problem if I try it with r 2.15 and earlier versions of both NetLogo and the extension. I reckon that the instructions that I'm following are for Mountain Lion, but I wonder if that is the problem. Anyone out there who has managed to get the extension working on Yosemite?

Comment: Would you please post the entire stack trace? There might be something helpful there. I'm not familiar with the R-extension, but if it's something on NetLogo's end, we might be able to pinpoint it through that.

Comment: I don't get a stack trace. The error appears as soon as I enter `extensions [r]` to the code tab.

Comment: Hm. Does it give you the option to "Show Details" in the error pop up? I thought it would. If it does, that should show you the stack trace. If not, I don't think I can be of much (or any) help.

Comment: There is no popup, the error appears in one of those yellow banners shown on top of the code tab when there are problems in the code.

Comment: Ack, sorry. I wouldn't even know where to begin, then. Good luck.

Comment: There might be a stack trace on the system console (open the Console application in the Utilities folder under Applications).

Comment: Nothing happens in the console when I repeat the steps described above. Is the console app the only place where things are logged?.

Comment: Yes. You may need to take this up with the authors of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Set environment variables for R: an R.dll and R.exe should be found in C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64 (depends on the path in step 1: Download and install R),

Set at first the R_HOME variable to C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1.

Now, append the PATH variable by %R_HOME%/bin/x64 (or directly by C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64).

You can refer the install document of of Netlogo R-exension in more detail.