# Error in using R-extension: Mac OS X El Capitan, NetLogo 5.2.1

Tags: r, netlogo

I'm getting the error "Error in R-Extension: Error in runOnce: java.lang.NullPointerException" when I try to use the r-extension. A similar question was given in [NetLogo R Extension Installation Error in Mac OS X Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27190975/netlogo-r-extension-installation-error-in-mac-os-x-yosemite/33764638#33764638) but I'm wondering if running Mac OS El X Capitan is causing a problem. I'm running NetLogo 5.2.1. 
I have followed the instructions on the R-extension page, and have modified the Info.plist file with the following code according to the developer instructions.

```
<key>NSJavaRoot</key>
<string>..</string>
<key>LSEnvironment</key>
<dict>
<key>JRI_HOME</key>
<string>/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/rJava/jri</string>
<key>R_HOME</key>
<string>/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources</string>
</dict>
</dict>
</plist>.
```

When I run the r-extension systemcheck, it says that my JAVA_HOME and JRI_HOME variables are "null". I'm not sure why I'm still not setting the environment for these variables correctly. Can someone please help with what I'm missing? I also tried loading the rJava package again, but it did nothing.

Comment: Also, when I view the environment variables R_HOME and JRI_HOME from my terminal, the contain the paths which are given in the instructions for the r-extension. So I'm even more confused why Im getting these variables as null when I run the extension in NetLogo.

Answer (score 0):

You should try,

```
<key>NSJavaRoot</key>
<string>..</string>
<key>LSEnvironment</key>
<dict>
<key>JRI_HOME</key>
<string>/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/rJava/jri</string>
<key>R_HOME</key>
<string>/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/rJava/jri</string>
</dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```