# Unable to work with R-extension in NetLogo

Tags: r, netlogo

I downloaded and installed the R-3.3.0 extension for windows. But when i run a netlogo code with extensions [r  matrix] (BEFERGYONET MODEL), an error occurs. The error is

Error in R-Extension: Error in runOnce: java.lang.NullPointerException

I read the documentation in the doc folder and various similar posts, then understood that some global environment variables (R_HOME, JRI_HOME and PATH) are need to be changed. But i did not understood how to make these changes and what exactly have to write for these variables. Is there any specific editor and commands to do so.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27190975/netlogo-r-extension-installation-error-in-mac-os-x-yosemite ... but this question doesn't have an accepted answer, but you can still try the suggested answer

Comment: Hello @Gaurav I have checked this before I asked, My question is not the same. I am asking bit more after reading those replies because I tried them and did not succeeded. So, please help by reading my question one more time.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example of your error?

Comment: @Gaurav, I have replied the example error in my another question, please check it there. thank you.